# RxJava. Join all the items from two Observable / Flowable streams

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I am loading some items to show on a single web page. In parallel I am loading the prices for the items. Simplified it looks like this:

```
Observable<Integer> ids =  itemIdsToShow(); // COLD Observable
Observable<Item> items = ids.flatMap(id -> loadingItem(id));
Observable<Price> prices = ids.flatMap(id -> loadingPrice(id));
```

UPDATE: Both "items" and "prices" are NOT ordered.

Now I want to join them together.

```
Observable<Long> wait = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable<Pair<Item, Price>> pairs = items.join(prices, (ii)->wait, (pp)->wait, Pair::of);

Observable<Item2> items2 = pairs.filter(p->p.a.id == p.b.id).map(p->new Item2(p.a, p.b));
```

It works, but the Observable "wait" looks strange. Alternatively I can use any Observable which never completes. Actually I need an observable, which completes as both "items" and "prices" complete.

The next suggestion does not work.

```
Observable<Object> wait = items.mergeWith(prices).takeLast(1);
```

Method "join" subscribes this new created Observable again, which initiates a new generation of the ID sequence (and everything starts from the beginning).

I am pretty sure, there is a clean and good looking way to do a full join without creating a custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) does exactly this.  For your example you'd end up with something like:

```
Observable.zip(Item, Price, Pair<Item, Price>)(items, prices, 
BiFunction { item, price ->
    Pair(item, price)
})
```

You can see an example of this explained in more detail [here](http://blog.jimbaca.com/2017/09/23/how-to-get-two-different-types-onto-the-same-stream/).

Edit: Per the updated question, they aren't ordered because [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) doesn't preserve order.  Instead checkout [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap(rx.functions.Func1)) which does ([direct link to the marble diagram](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/concatMap.png)).

Comment: It works only, if the the data generated in the same order by both of the observables. It is not the case :-(

Comment: checkout concatMap instead of flatMap

Comment: The fetching part is very simplified in the question. Originally it consist of a long chain of Observables including multiplexing and demultiplexing. If I replace all the "flatMap" calls by "concatMap", it makes the code less readable and it will lose the benefits of a concurrent execution. |||||| This questions is less about the fetching, but more about joining.